# "Communication with apple failed" when signing in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

Just created fresh user account to test that issue.

- In new account open Xcode 8.0
- Start new project
- In General settings pressed 'Add account' button (else it fails to run on a device)
- When adding a team (I did not enroll into $99 Apple Developer Program) it shows these errors:

  **Communication with Apple failed** The response data was not a valid plist.
  **No profiles for '...' were found** Xcode couldn't find a provisioning profile matching '...'.
  [image: ss]

How to fix?
Maybe I’m doing it completely wrong. Is it possible to run the app on a device without enrolling into $99 program?

UPDATE:
Ok, I know now that I should be able to test my app on the device even without enrolling.
Moreover it was working fine before I’ve tested the app on few more devices (iPhones of my friends). After that it stop working on my iPhone

Comment: is iOS device connected to mac? No, if you only want to run it then no need for enrolling.

Comment: @pradeep1991singh, yeah I’ve connected the device.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a fix? Surprisingly, using my friends 'personal team' account works. its only mine thats blocked.

Comment: @NSRover I ended up creating new project in new user account with new apple ID. Then I’ve abandoned the work on iOS app for a while. Hope thinks got fixed when I’ll give another try

Comment: @oluckyman I'm not so sure about that. I think our certificate requests for Personal team is just stuck in limbo with no way to cancel it. I really hope Apple fixes this at some point. I don't want to abandon my account.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a device and free developer account, that's enough to install and test your game...

Go to General Settings, and set your Team. I can see its already done.
To make sure you logged in to XCode, Go to Xcode-> Preferences->Accounts,
give your developer account login credentials

Connect device, it shows up after 3-5 seconds, select the device and run.
XCode prompts it can't find a valid provisioning profile with "FIX NOW" button, just press it and run again....

Comment: as you may see there is no "FIX NOW" button anymore. So I’m assuming that it’s something new in Xcode 8.0 signing process and it does not work well

Answer (score 0):

I create a new Certificate in iTunesConnect than click try again,It works.
I don't know why